# linker mismatch in msvc version. Is there any workaround for it?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to builda c++ code which was developed  VS 2010

I can compile it, but during link, I am getting this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in myfile.obj
```

I know that it is because they are build with different version of MSVC, but is there any way that I can configure MSVC to use libraries compiled with older version of MSVC?

**Edit 1**

At the end , I  decided to install VS2012 express and compile code with it. It seems the Microsoft doesn't like you to port one project from one version of MSVC to another one easily.

Comment: Did you found a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three solutions to solve this problem :

- Recompile the VS2010 library in 2012 (but you need the sources). Or if there is already an available 2012 library (but you already check it I guess).
- Or you can do :

> In Project Properties, select General and then change the "Platform Toolset" setting to "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)."
>
> Or you can link your library as external.

Comment: After setting platform to 2010, I am getting this error: Error 1 error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 2010 build tools.     What do I need to install? A full version of MSVC 2010 or is there any file that only install the 2010 build system?

Comment: Effectively, I have it on my computer... I don't know if there is a workaround to avoid installing VS2010...

Answer (score 1):

MSVC static libraries are binary incompatible between major versions (at least those which use Microsoft's STL implementation):

> C++ Standard Library implementation intentionally breaks binary
>   compatibility among versions of Visual Studio (2005, 2008, 2010,
>   2012). ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx))

You can either:

- recompile external library with same compiler
- move your code to compiler same that external library use
- link external library dynamically (.dll)